# Go Back to SwiftUi View from UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swiftui, uikit, swiftui-navigationlink, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I want to return to the previous view via a UIViewController button in a UIViewControllerRepresentable.

When I click on uiButtonBack, nothing happens.

What is wrong in my code?

MainContent:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
         NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: MyUIKitView()) { Text("Go to UIKit View") }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Main View")
        }
    }
}
```

UIViewControllerRepresentable:

```
struct MyUIKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyUiViewController {
        let viewController = MyUiViewController()
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyUiViewController, context: Context) { }
}
```

UIViewController:

```
class MyUiViewController: UIViewController {

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainView.uiButtonBack.addTarget(self,
                                           action: #selector(back),
                                           for: .touchUpInside)
        mainView.uiButtonBack.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
    }

    @objc func back() {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Thanks to help me.

Comment: Did you make sure your navigationController is not nil?

Comment: it doesn't seem like it. I get into the condition when I do:`if let nav = self.navigationController { nav.popToRootViewController(animated: true) }`, 
Now I'm wondering if `.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` is the correct use when using UIViewController in a UIViewControllerRepresentable

Comment: Did you also try with a simple `popViewController`?

Comment: By the way, I copied and pasted your code, removing those mainView references ant it works. It navigates back just fine.

Comment: thank you for helping, Sweeper helps me to resolve my bug! Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting the view controller hierarchy, it seems like SwiftUI wraps the content of the `NavigationView` into some sort split view controller by default.

If you set the style of the `NavigationView` to `.stack`, your code works correctly.

```
NavigationView {
    ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

If you don't need to support versions before iOS 16, you should use `NavigationStack` instead, which also makes `popToRootViewController` work correctly.

```
NavigationStack {
    VStack {
        NavigationLink {
            MyUIKitView()
        } label: {
            Text("Go to UIKit View")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Main View")
}
```

That said, using `popToRootViewController` depends on the fact that SwiftUI wraps your UIKit view controller in a `UINavigationController`, which might change in the future. IMO, it is better to just pass the `dismiss` action from the SwiftUI side to the UIKit side:

```
struct MyUIKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyUiViewController {
        let viewController = MyUiViewController()
        
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyUiViewController, context: Context) { 
        uiViewController.dismissAction = dismiss
    }
}
```

```
class MyUiViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var dismissAction: DismissAction?
    
    override func loadView() {
        // ...
    }

    @objc func back() {
        dismissAction?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will stay for the first solution, because my main project is iOS 14 and above, and it works !!!